# Put two or more images on video

Tags: ffmpeg, video

According [this](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12105/add-an-image-overlay-in-front-of-video-using-ffmpeg) I try to put two pictures on video

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i photo01.jpg -i photo02.jpg  -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,10,20)';[0:v][2:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,25,35)'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4
```

no errors, but it shows only the first image, and the second is not show up.

Answer (score 0):

So i find solution, making a chain

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i image.png -i image2.png  -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,1,10)'[1];[1][2:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,15,25)'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4
```